# Why bcrypt.compareSync() is always returning me a false

Tags: express, validation, bcrypt, express-validator

I'm comparing the password from a FORM in a login view, with the password in a database in .JSON. But even when I see in the console that both are the same, the method is always returning a false.

```
             for (let i = 0; i<users.length; i++) {
               if (users[i].email == req.body.email) {

                console.log(req.body.password); //Here I notice that both passwords are the same
                console.log(users[i].password);

               **  if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, users[i].password)) {
                 var loggedUser= users[i]
                 console.log("correct password");
                 break
                }

                else{
                console.log("wrong password");
                }**

           }
      }
```

Comment: "Here I notice that both passwords are the same". How did you know both passwords are correct? `user[i].password` is hashed and `req.body.password` is plain text.

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether you hash the user's password correctly or not. Because of `req.body.password` and `users[i]`. Password must be different.

Comment: Hi, in the console, I can check if both passwords are the same

    console.log(req.body.password); //Here I notice that both passwords are the same
    console.log(users[i].password);

for example:

req.body.password = abcde
users[i].password = abcde

Comment: Please send the part where you hash the user's password here if possible.

Comment: @ManuelAlejandroGarcaAndrade You are clearly not hashing the password.          `users[i].password=abcde` it is not hashed.